# Why does Array.map() method returns arr[index+1].length as undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a strange error when using Array.map() method. Why does 
arrayElementLength=strarr[index+1].length throws an error that its undefined (even though it works)

```js
function longestConsec(strarr, k) {
    // your code
    let solution = [];
    strarr.map((string, index, arr) => {

    let arrayElementLength = strarr[index+1].length;
    console.log(arrayElementLength);

        if(string.length == arrayElementLength){
            solution.push(string);
        }
    });
    return solution;
}

console.log(longestConsec(["zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas"], 2))
```

Comment: Not using `map()` properly either. It is intended to create a new array. If all you want is to loop over an array use `forEach()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you reach to the last index of `strArr` than with `index+1` you're trying to access index which is not present in array, and this is cause of the this error `strarr[(index + 1)] is undefined`

```js
function longestConsec(strarr, k) {
    // your code
    let solution=[];
    strarr.map((string,index,arr)=>{
    let arrayElementLength=strarr[index+1].length;
    console.log(arrayElementLength);
if(string.length==arrayElementLength){
    solution.push(string);
}
    })
    return solution;
}

   console.log(longestConsec(["zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas"], 2))
```

On side note: you're not using return value of map so it's better to use `forEach`

Answer (score 2):

> Why does arrayElementLength=strarr[index+1].length throws an error that its undefined (even though it works)

No, it does not work in the last iteration. The array index starts from `0`. With `strarr[index+1]`, in the last iteration, your code tries to access the item from an index which really does not exist and returns `undefined`.

```js
var sampleArr = ['test'];
console.log(sampleArr[0]); //test
console.log(sampleArr[1]); //undefined
```

So, remove `+1` from the index part and your code will work as expected:

```js
function longestConsec(strarr, k) {
    // your code
    let solution=[];
    strarr.map((string,index,arr)=>{
      let arrayElementLength=strarr[index].length;
      console.log(arrayElementLength);
      if(string.length==arrayElementLength){
          solution.push(string);
      }
    })
    return solution;
}

console.log(longestConsec(["zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas"], 2))
```

Comment: *"really does not exist"* ... it does for most iterations

Comment: @CodeManiac, OP really didn't clarify about the logic and intended output:)

Comment: @Mamun agree. even i am not sure what is the use of second parameter in function `k`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not strange, the array index starts at 0 so the last index + 1 will be undefined.
Furthermore, `Array.map` is usually used to "map" the given array to a new array, the way you are using it would be more appropriate to use `Array.forEach`.

```
function longestConsec(strarr, k) {
  let solution = [];
  strarr.forEach((string, index, arr) => {
    let arrayElementLength = strarr[index].length;
    console.log(arrayElementLength);
    if(string.length === arrayElementLength){
      solution.push(string);
    }
  })
  return solution;
}

console.log(longestConsec(["zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas"], 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have already mentioned, you're getting the error when the loop reaches the last element. `strarr[index+1]` returns `undefined` and you can't access it's `length`.

Looking at your code, if your intention is to get all the items which have the same `length` as the next element, [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) suits your purpose much better:

```js
function longestConsec(strarr, k) {
  return strarr.filter((string, index) => {
    return index !== strarr.length - 1
            && string.length === strarr[index + 1].length
  })
}

console.log(longestConsec(["zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas"], 2))
```

I have added an additional check `index !== strarr.length - 1` if the loop has encountered the last element.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.map` iterates over every element in the map and the `index` (second argument) is the current index, now if you reach the last element in the array you're mapping, the next element (`index + 1`) simply does not exist.

If the function as a whole is trying to obtain the longest streak of same length stings, you might just want to `reduce` the base array.

```js
function longestConsec(arr) {
  return arr
    .reduce((carry, string) => {
      const prev = carry[carry.length - 1];
      const length = string.length;
    
      if (!prev || prev.length !== string.length) {
        carry.push({ length, strings: [string] });
      }
      else {
        prev.strings.push(string);
      }
      
      return carry;
    }, [])
    .sort((one, two) => two.strings.length - one.strings.length)
    .shift().strings;
}


console.log(longestConsec(["zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas"]))
```

(Note that I removed the `k` argument from the function, as it didn't seem to be used)